# How can I split data read from a json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this json data in `data.json` file.

```
[
"1009 2000",
"1009 2001",
"1002 2002",
"1003 2002"
]
```

I am looping through this data and spliting the data based on `,` as in the following code

```
var show = function () {
    var span = $('.input');
    var c = $('ul');
    $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (id) {
        var j = id.split(',');
        var hsl = j[0];
        var ny = j[1];

        $('<li>' + id + '</li>').appendTo(c);
        $(c).appendTo(span);
        console.log(hsl);
    });
}
```

but this gives me this error in console

```
Object 1009 2000,1009 2001,1002 2002,1003 2002 has no method 'split'
```

How can I split this data so that I could display it like this

```
 1009 2000
 1009 2001
 1002 2002
 1003 2002
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on a json object? Your object is an array.

Comment: You don't have to split the object

Comment: indeed, you can split a string to make an array out of it, but there is no sense in splitting an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split anything, simply loop:

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function (ids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```

jQuery will automatically parse the string returned from the server as a javascript array so that you could directly access its elements.

You could split each element by the space if you want to retrieve the 2 tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The id variable is actually the array, since getJson parses it for you. Just loop over the array and print each item.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mean to say that the data being returned is a string, and you need to convert it to an array.

```
$.getJSON('data/data.json', function(id) {

    id = JSON.parse(id);
    for(var i=0, len=id.length; i<len; i++){
        //do your stuff here
    }
});
```